# Question about parsing some character in a bitset in STL

Tags: c++, templates, binaryfiles, binary-data, bitset

I am working on a project and i believe that i currently need to manipulate bits.

The whole idea is that i am parsing a binary file and i have to extract records that are 106 bytes each. Since a file can have eg 10 records, i decided to put every record in a bitset(be getting the char from the ifstream and appending it with the << operator on my bitset). My general idea of what i want to return looks something like that:

`

```
template <size_t N>class calls : public bin<N> {

std::vector<std::bitset<N>> getFile(const std::string &fileName) override {

    std::ifstream in(fileName, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);

    std::vector<std::bitset<CALLS_CHUNK_SIZE>> result;

    auto iterator = result.begin();

    std::bitset<CALLS_CHUNK_SIZE> bits;

    assert(in);

    char c;

    int counter = 0;

    while(in.get(c)){

        if(counter == CALLS_CHUNK_SIZE){
            result.push_back(bits);

            //is there a way to reset my bitset to an empty bitset again so i can keep pushing every new record as a bitset in my vector?
        }

        bits<<c;

        counter++;


    }

}
```

`

Do you think that this idea is okay or should i do something different which would be more efficient/effective/ in general a better solution?

After i extract my data i should reinterpret them some as characters, some as numbers etc...

Please note that the code is incomplete and i am kind of a beginner in C++.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need a `std::bitset`? You you have `106` **bytes**, use `std::array<char, 106>`. `bits << c;` is not doing what you think it does - it doesn't insert `c` into `bits`.

Comment: @Evg thanks for your response, i changed that and it seems kinda easier. I f i want to convert some of the parsed results as strings or char arrays, lets say i got 31303038360000000000 as a possible field and need to get it to a string / array of chars(the result i should get is 10086), how can i do that?

Comment: Where is `10086` in `31303038360000000000`?

Comment: @Evg when i am parsing the file and got the raw binary in hex using a hex editor this particular number was converted to 10086 (https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html) . It is correct since i have an idea of how the result should look like.

Comment: Do you use `std::array<char, 106>` now? `31303038360000000000` is represented as text or as bytes?

Comment: @Evg this one works but i have an issue with other positions. For example my first sequence that i get in hex from the binary is FF00FFFF00000000 which in the logic of the header corresponds to something like "this is a received call where the phone number is not saved" but as a sequence of characters it is ÿ.ÿÿ... . My main idea is to hardcode something like #define RECEIVED_NOT_SAVED 'FF00FFFF00000000' and compare it with the find function(first i converted the original std::array to string) but it finds it in every string while it should be found in only 2.

Comment: @Evg thats why i am trying to compare them as either both as chars or strings but i cannot

Comment: https://prnt.sc/q49y3k here you can see what i am trying to do

Comment: You should draw a distinction between hex as chars and hex as values. For example `30` corresponds to `0` character. Don't use `ÿ` and strings for something that is not a string. Use arrays of hex values `std::array<RECEIVED_NOT_SAVED, length> = {0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, ...};` and then use `std::equal` to check for range equality. I suggest you ask a separate question if this one has been resolved.